# Removing schema qualification from all data-source queries in a .accdb file programatically

Tags: ms-access, adp, dbo

I have a huge .accdb file that is being created from a now unsupported .adp file.

So far, I have imported all objects and my tables are now linked tables, which I have renamed to remove the automatic prefix 'dbo_'.

The next step is to remove all the schema qualifications, `dbo.` from data-source queries from all reports and forms.

I have thousands of controls on forms and reports with data-sources that need the " dbo." and " [dbo]." removing their queries.

**Example**

A form contains a combobox control, and the data-source is set to the following:

```
SELECT name FROM dbo.person WHERE building = 'reception'
```

I need some code that will change this data-source (along with all the others in all other forms) to:

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE building = 'reception'
```

Does anybody know how to do this programatically?

Comment: If [Find and Replace 9.0](http://www.rickworld.com/products.html) works for your Access version, it would be my choice.

Comment: That's a tall order, especially for all object including queries and forms and...  Many/most objects are accessible via the Access object model, but there is no way an answer on SO could outline all details.  Instead, I recommend starting with [V-Tools](http://www.skrol29.com/us/vtools.php).  Beside having tools to do this, the code is accessible and can be reviewed as an example of how to program it yourself.

Comment: I also recommend Find and Replace.

Comment: Yes, Find and Replace saved my sanity more than once. Well worth the $35. I have heard of freebie V-Tools but not used.

Comment: I can't argue against Find and Replace since I've never used it, but V-Tools that I linked to is free and it also has a find and replace feature and some other handy tools.  As always, make a backup before doing any changes with either tool.

Comment: The link for V-Tools is http://www.skrol29.com/us/vtools.php